# In VB.Net I use following code to send the email. Now I want to use TLS authentication

Tags: vb.net, smtp, client, ssl

I use following code to send the email.

```
Dim smtpCli As New SmtpClient
.
.
.
.
smtpCli.EnableSsl = True
smtpCli.Send(mailMsg)
```

Now I want to use TLS while sending the email. How to do it in VB.NET?

Comment: SSL and TLS are different names (and versions) of the same protocol line. When you enable SSL, you enable TLS as well. Are you having a problem with delivery?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here, and wonder if you are trying to use System.Net.Mail against amazon SES (I've seen this question about 10x in the past 30days on this and other sites).

System.Net.Mail doesn't work against Amazon SES, because Amazon requires SSL (TLS) before the SMTP session starts. System.Net.Mail switches to SSL after the SMTP starts.